# Where does ui javascript belong in the MVVM model (with knockout)?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Say you're starting with a website that has UI affects done through jquery. For instance a, menu.  Clicking an anchor will apply a class to this to show the anchor is the active anchor.  This is done in jquery on dom ready -

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu a").click(function(){
           $("#menu a").removeClass('active');   
           $(this).addClass('active');
      });
});
```

Now, say this menu is dynamically generated with knockout bindings -

```
$(function() {
      $("#menu a").click(function(){
               $("#menu a").removeClass('active');   
               $(this).addClass('active');
          });

    ko.applyBindings();

});

<ul id="menu" data-bind="foreach: menuItem">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: menuText"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The click event won't be attached to these items, because the ko.applyBindings happens on dom ready.  I know there are events like afterRender that could be used to fix this, but it's seems cleaner to use the ViewModel -

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: menuItem">
        <li>
            <a data-bind="text: menuText, 
                          click:setActive, css: {active: someComputed }"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What is the correct way to do this with the MVVM pattern? Or what is the proper way to do this with knockout? Through the viewmodel seems to be the cleanest, but where does it stop? Would you have javascript to make it a dropdown menu on mouseover in the ViewModel?

Comment: use delegation: $("#menu").on("click", "a", fn). or move the script bock to the template so they update together.

Comment: I would recommend you to go through the knockout documentation ( I know it's not something ). I would also recommend to use knockout event listeners since they are really well implemented and you don't have to worry about disposing stuff after they lose reference - knockout will do that for you

Comment: Good question, as you have two technologies colliding.  Both are capable and neither in and of themselves violates MVVM concepts. Question is do you want to control view state by data or by JQUERY UI? Maybe you currently have a lot of JQUERY UI in the site, in that case it could be better to stick with it.  If it's a new site, then maybe KO is more preferable as you move to true data binding technique for everything!  KO falls short; however, in animation, for that JQuery UI is better. (IMO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an isSelected observable to the menu item and then toggle that when the menu item is clicked (using the click binding). Then you can use the css binding in the view which will use isSelected.

As you can see when you are using knockout it's best to just interact with the view model instead of interacting with the dom as you would if you were using jQuery.

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.menuItems = [
        new MenuItem('Text1'),
        new MenuItem('Text2'),
        new MenuItem('Text3'),
        new MenuItem('Text4')
    ];

    self.toggleMenuItem = function (menuItem) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.menuItems.length; i++) {
            self.menuItems[i].isSelected(false);
        }
        menuItem.isSelected(true);
    };
};

var MenuItem = function (menuText) {
    var self = this;

    self.menuText = menuText;
    self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
};

<ul id="menu" data-bind="foreach: menuItems">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="text: menuText, click: $parent.toggleMenuItem, css: { active: isSelected }"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d625vaad/1/

Comment: And Wayne shows yet another concept which is the client-side Viewmodel.  This is something that Angular is opening up and the community appears to be running to client side View Models, Controllers and even Routing.

Comment: @JohnPeters This is a knockout question not an Angular question so try to stay on topic. This page talks about MVVM and what the difference is between the model, view and viewModel: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html.

Comment: Did not realize mere mention of another framework was need for castigation.  Here's a suggestion for you, just ignore what I said.